# "Fatal Error : Could not find device " error while trying to download program to the MCU

Tags: msp430, debugging, iar

[image][![enter image description here][2]][2]I'm using MSP430F5131 and trying to program it by IAR Embedded Workbench while using the MSP-FET debugger.

**A short background of the PCB**:

After i compiled the code in IAR with not errors found , i connected the MSP-FET to the MSP430 in a Spi-Bi-Wire connection according to the datasheet.
The MSP430 is placed in a PCB which includes 12V input voltage and 2 regulators of 5V and 3.3V . The MSP430 I/O's are connected according to the datasheet (including external pullup resistors and capacitors) along with the Spi-Bi-Wire connections.
I energized the PCB with a 12V supply voltage , connected the MSP-FET's connector to a Header connector on the PCB and the other side connected to the PC by USB.

**My problem is** :

In the IAR , once i try to download the code into the MSP430 (by clicking the 'Download and Debug' button) it says that it needs a firmware update , so i clicked ok and download the new update , but when it tries to initialize hardware i encounter the error :

"Fatal error: Could not find device (or device not supported)

Session aborted!"

I have tried multiple things in order to find the solution - with no success .

Does the AVcc and AVss needs to be connected **even if i dont use any analog options**? coz its not connected to anything.

I also tried to download the program to the MSP430 with code composer studio but encounter the same error.

The error pops up even if i dont connect the MSP-FET to the MCU (only to the PC by the USB cable).

I have connected the MSP-FET to the MCU like that :

- RST/NMI/SBWTDIO of the MCU to TDO/TDI pin 1 of the MSP-FET.
- TEST/SBWTCK of the MCU to TCK pin 7 of the MSP-FET.
- a 3.3V that is supplied from a regulator in the PCB to VCC_TOOL pin 2 of the     MSP-FET.
- GND of the PCB to GND pin 9 of the MSP-FET.

Here's the error message i get:

[![The Error window][2]][2]

Here's the IAR settings for the FET Debugger:

[![FET Debugger settings][3]][3]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Comment: I would say your circuit is not wired properly.

Comment: Just a remark regarding your AVcc and AVss connections: AVcc should be connected to DVcc and AVss should be connected to DVss. See section 1.6 "Connection of Unused Pins" from the "MSP430x5xx and MSP430x6xx Family User's Guide"

Comment: yes you are right . it's written in the family user's guide , the wierd thing is that its not the first time we programmed the MCU with the same PCB , so you suggest that i should short those pins and see if that works for me?

Comment: This is what TI suggests. Try and tell us. Unfortunately, I have no clue if that will help or not.

Comment: alright thank you , just one last question , is it supposed to be connected permanently? or just for the program downloading?

Comment: "Tue Jan 24, 2017 10:33:24: Using license: Standalone license - IAR Embedded Workbench for Texas Instruments MSP430 
Tue Jan 24, 2017 10:33:25: Firmware version 3.9.0.0 
Tue Jan 24, 2017 10:33:25: Interface dll version 3.9.1.2 
Tue Jan 24, 2017 10:33:27: Unknown device : (OpenDevice) , Device=MSP430F5131, PwLength=0x0 
Tue Jan 24, 2017 10:33:28: Fatal error: Could not find device (or device not supported)   Session aborted! "     This is the error as it apears in the Log

Comment: Well, it's very hard to tell then. Have you measured all power lines on your MCU (DVIO, DVCC and VCORE)?  Can you post a schematic of your circuit? This might help a little.

Comment: I edited the first post and added the MCU electrical schematic . I havn't measured those power lines yet.

Comment: Thanks. But could you also add a debugger connector section? I don't see pull-up for reset line for instance.

Comment: oh yes sorry i forgot to add this one. ill edit and add again to the first post. I was thinking maybe the IAR or the MSP-FET don't support my MCU (MSP430F5131) do you think that might be the problem?

Comment: Schematic looks fine to me. Regarding IAR: I don't know, I personally used only CCS for MSP430, but you also mentioned that you have also tried CCS, haven't you? Btw, with CCS you can open View->Target Configurations, double click on the configuration file (.ccxml extension) and test the debugger connection. You need to select your MCU and then you can push Test Connection button.

Comment: NB! I have read your post once again more careful, and noticed that you have a mistake in the wiring, if you use local power suppl, then you need to connect you local 3.3V line to the pin 4 VCC_TARGET of MSP-FET, and not to pin 2.

Comment: OK so i moved it to pin 4 and i tried to download it but the CCS pops an error that says : "Error initializing emulator:
Interface Communication error" . In the Target Configuration the test button is disabled - cant click on it.

Comment: ok now i get another error : "MSP430: Error connecting to the target: Unknown device"

Comment: Well, then my suggestion list would be: 1) As already mentioned above, check all power lines; 2) Go through debugger [troubleshooting list](http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Debugging_JTAG_Connectivity_Problems); 3) Make sure that the debugger MSP-FET is really working (test it with some other board/launchpad); 4) Post your problem on [TI forum](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/);

Comment: I measured the voltage between DVcc and DVss and the call is 0.7V , isnt it supposed to be 3.3V? maybe thats the problem?

Comment: Well, that's definitely IS a problem. MCU can not even run when the DVCC < 1.8V. Check your regulator.

Comment: For those readers who want to "follow the story", the OP has followed an earlier suggestion to post the problem on the TI forum - this new question was added to an old thread there, starting at [this point](https://e2e.ti.com/support/microcontrollers/msp430/f/166/p/100820/2086805#2086805).

Answer (score 0):

You have definitely made a critical mistake by not connecting the AVCC and AVSS pins to the proper supply voltages (VCC, GND). You mention this board has worked before? I don't see how that is possible given these pins were connected to their proper supply even if the FET was providing your board power.

Can you post a picture of your PCB layout? Are you getting exactly 3.3V outside your linear regulator? Measure the voltage across C5 or C7 to find out. The error you're getting is typically a power supply issue, but I see you have shorted AVSS and AVCC in your previous posts.

Comment: I still havn't shorted the AVcc and AVss to DVcc and DVss - working on it . The voltage i get when i measure across C5 or C7 is 0.7V - This seems like the voltage of the regulator output for some reason , maybe 3.3v rail is shorted somewhere....

Comment: I'm sorry but i dont have the PCB layout only the Electronic schematic

Comment: Troubleshoot the 3.3V regulator first then, can you post the entire schematic of that 3.3V section? The picture that is posted cuts the input side circuitry.

Comment: Alright i posted the entire schmatic of the PCB at my first post

Comment: Are you at least getting 5V across C3 and C4?

Comment: Yes i get 5V across these capacitors.

Comment: I think something is wrong with the PCB and not just that specific device...we are checking the problem

Comment: ok now the pcb works fine but i still get the same error : after i click on the debugging in the code composer studio i get the error : couldnt find the target device . i double checked the pcb and the MSP430 gets at least 1.8v in order to work fine...i still dont understand whats the problem is....

Comment: I still havn't figured out the problem . the board works just fine